# save-excursion and find-function-at-point

Tags: save-excursion

The `find-function-at-point` command finds a function and displays its definition in the other window, while moving point to the other window as well.

I'd like to have a version of `find-function-at-point` that opens the function definition in the other window, but leaves point in the current window.

I thought I could accomplish this with `save-excursion` in a lambda expression as follows:

```
(lambda ()
 (interactive)
 (save-excursion)
 (find-function-at-point))))
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. Point remains in the other window.

My understanding of `save-excursion` is that it should restore point and mark after the body of `save-excursion` is evaluated. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your call to `save-excursion` has no body.

It is saving point, mark, and the current buffer, then *doing nothing*, and then 'restoring' those things to their saved values.

However that's the wrong macro. You want `save-selected-window`.

It sounds like you are under the misconception that there is a *single* `point` and `mark` which 'move' around between buffers. This is not the case -- each buffer has its own buffer-local `point` and `mark` values -- so "restoring point and mark" has nothing to do with changing the currently-selected window.

Nor indeed does "restoring the current buffer" -- that is simply the *buffer* (which is not necessarily visible in any window) which is current for the functions being called. "Restoring" this value has no bearing on whether/where that buffer is displayed.

In short, be aware that buffers are independent of the windows they can be displayed in. Mixing the two concepts in your mind will certainly lead to confusion.

Comment: Well put. Good way to make this clear.

Comment: You're absolutely right that I've associated "buffers" with "windows" in my mind. Your explanation made this very clear!